# Symmetricds - Configure data model schema

Tags: symmetricds

When trying to setup a target to VoltDB, SymmetricDS fails on schema creation (specifically the table - SYM_INCOMING_ERROR).

Is there a setting to change the schema without having to recompile?

```
[voltdb] - AbstractSymmetricEngine - An error occurred while starting
SymmetricDS

org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: General Provider Error
(GRACEFUL_FAILURE): 'Error: Table SYM_INCOMING_ERROR has a maximum row size
of 2403801 but the maximum supported row size is 2097152'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would export the DDL SQL, fix the issue and apply it using flyway or liquibase